# What is a proper way to pass additional parameters in a 'slug-url'

Tags: http, web-applications

Let's a assume a blog with comments and the user views one blog post with a lot of comments. A nice URL to the blog post may look like:

```
http://www.example.com/blog/174/how_to_slug_urls
```

174 is the database id of the blog post. Since there are too many comments to display on one page, the comments get splitted over pages.

Is there some common way to pass the comment page parameter? Do i append it before the slug, after the slug, send it per POST, or is there some complete other way?

examples i can think of:

```
http://www.example.com/blog/174/how_to_slug_urls/commentpage/4
http://www.example.com/blog/174/how_to_slug_urls?commentpage=4
http://www.example.com/blog/174/how_to_slug_urls#commentpage=4   // maybe parsing with JS?
http://www.example.com/blog/commentpage/4/174/how_to_slug_urls
```

**edit:**
additional question: How to handle parameters which are not connected to the current data? e.g. refreshIntervall=30s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a comment page is a resource, i.e. something independently addressable, which it clearly is intended to be here, then the first URL is ok. I'd make it 'http://www.example.com/blog/174/how_to_slug_urls/commentpages/4' though. Note the 's'. As in 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927056'.

And the comments for a blog post are obviously subordinate to the blog post itself, so the hierarchy is preserved in that url, as opposed to your last example.

Comment: good point, and how would you handle other parameters? (see edit)

Comment: That's a querystring parameter since it's not a resource, more an arbitrary piece of extra data, so I'd simply stick ?refreshInterval=30 at the end. NOT "30s".

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there are two viable options in this situation.

**Option 1: just use the query string.** (ie `http://www.example.com/blog/article/174/how_to_slug_urls?commentpage=4`)

Note that I added `article/`.  It's not necessary, but I feel that presents the URI in a more readable manner.

I recommend using a query string when you feel like the comments are a part of the same resource (the blog article) but need a separate URI solely for pagination purposes.

**Option 2: use a completely different URI.** (ie `http://www.example.com/blog/comments/174/how_to_slug_urls?page=4`)

Note that I STILL used a query string to distinguish the pages.

A visually dissimilar URI clearly conveys that the comments are a separate resource. This may not be how you view the comments, but it is how I view them.

**Compare:**

`http://www.example.com/blog/article/174/how_to_slug_urls?commentpage=4`

`http://www.example.com/blog/comments/174/how_to_slug_urls?page=4`

**Handling other parameters:** just use the the query string.

We seem to have an obsession with not using `?` in our URI's.  Some would say that they aren't pretty; I'd counter that looks aren't everything. If you really want to avoid it, the following URIs are . . . acceptable, I guess:

`http://www.example.com/blog/article/174/how_to_slug_urls/4`

`http://www.example.com/blog/comments/174/how_to_slug_urls/4`